# Node.js profiling: high usage in "(program)" section

Tags: node.js, profiling, google-chrome-devtools, v8

Configuration:

- Node.js 0.8.15
- Mac OSX 10.7.5
- [Webkit Devtools Agent](https://github.com/c4milo/node-webkit-agent) node module

While profiling, I've noticed a very high utilization in the "(program)" section of the profile.  "Manually" profiling (with node --prof and mac-tick-processor) shows a similarly high percentage spent in `___psynch_rw_unlock` in the C++ section.

The primary usage of the program during the profiling was:

- libxml processing
- tls socket reading / writing
- mongodb writing

[image: Screenshot]

Is this normal behavior, or is this a sign of a deeper problem?

Comment: I would assume this is expected, as this is where the bulk of the work is being done, yes?

Comment: Either that is where all the work is being done, in which case the profiler cannot determine the correct calling trace.  Or the profiler is incorrectly classifying idle times as (program).  I don't know enough about V8 to tell the difference.

Comment: Ah, I see.  The concern is that 91% of CPU on the system is being used, rather than 91% of non-idle time in your program is being spent on `(program)`.  I didn't realize the profile looked outside of your process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of now, Chrome classifies both native code and idle time as `(program)`. Now that http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/138004 has landed, let's see if it makes it into the next Chrome version...

Comment: Meanwhile, you can use canary to make use of this improvement.